# Document Class Memoir Headers

Tags: memoir

I'm using the document class memoir, and in the header for each chapter, it keeps reading 'Chapter 1. The Title of the Chapter'. Is there any way to remove the 'Chapter X' from the header? I've figured all of the other formatting issues out via Google, but I haven't been able to locate anything regarding this particular instance.

Comment: Are you using any predefined page style?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I set up my own page style (sort of) as an experiment, just trying to find a layout I like. Other than that, I've not change or redefined anything.

Comment: Ah, then my answer should do what you want. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\chaptermark`; for example:

```
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! It's too early, otherwise I'd accept it. +1. Would you mind explaining the meaning in the meantime? I saw similar things in the manual (of which I've only read portions trying to figure out how to get the layout I wanted), but the meaning itself has escaped me.

Comment: @anon271828 sure, but what do you want me to explain?

Comment: The #1 and \markboth. I'm currently looking at the manual to figure out *why* this does what I want it to.

Comment: Or a reference where I can learn the material fairly well in a brief (if possible) amount of time.

Comment: @anon271828 I am adding some explanations... the documentation for the `fancyhdr` package contains some information on the marking mechanism. The LaTeX Companion also has some explanations. In some minutes I'll add some other comments.

Comment: @anon271828 I must leave now, but tomorrow I'll finish with some other comments about `\marboth` and `\markright`.

Comment: That is way too complicated. This can be fixed with a memoir one liner. See addtopsmarks, add the change in the third argument. Or see my article about me our page styles, there is no reason to use that complicated code cited above (I'm on a tablet so I cannot post my solution at the moment)

Comment: @daleif I agree with you; this is one liner and my answer is exactly a one liner: `\def\chaptermark#1{ \markboth{#1}{}}`. All the other code that appears in my answer was just to give an explanation (that I still haven't finished) of the various commands involved in the marking mechanism, since the OP requested some explanation.

Comment: @anon271828 I don't have time to complete the explanation I was writing, so I decided to suppress it; sorry about that, but you can find information in the references I mentioned before.

Comment: And the user need to know about chaptermark and markboth.

Answer (score 4):

My solution

```
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
   \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

The default is

```
\createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
```